# How to seal p-trap leaking at inlet

Tags: plumbing, leak

My sink is leaking at the p-trap's inlet. It is plastic going from my garbage disposal into a metal fitting. It looks like it was sealed with something like petroleum jelly. I've wiped it off in this picture though since it obviously wasn't working anymore.

What is the appropriate way to seal this and prevent further leaking? Fortunately it seems I caught it earlier enough that not too much damage was done.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's leaking there?  A slow leak where the plastic elbow meets the disposal would run down the elbow and could give the appearance of leaking at the trap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not sealed with petroleum jelly but a beveled slip washer.  You can try to tighten the nut on the p-trap where the black pvc enters the copper p-trap.  If that does not work, you will need to get a new 1 1/2 beveled slip joint washer.  Your big box home improvement stores carry them as do any plumbing supply houses.

[image]

They also make rubber washers for this fitting:
[image]

But I prefer the beveled slip washer since it works on compression.

Comment: It's important to use the (flat) rubber washer that goes behind the beveled slip washer.  This provides even pressure on the beveled washer when there's a slight misalignment of the fitting.

Comment: This went exactly as planned. I also replaced the washer between the garbage disposal and plastic fitting. Both parts were available at ACE for a few dollars. The old washer was in pretty good shape, but it had become hardened over time.